# Indesign: how to export multiple PDFs using different presets at once

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export, batch-processing, indesign-scripting

I've got a series of documents that I need to export to 4 different PDFs. (High-res print ready, high-res no bleed, low-res online, and one last high-res with a different name).

Is there a script out there to run multiple exports with various PDF presets?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, here's a few:

- Free: http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/batch_convert.html
- Paid: http://zevrix.com/outputfactory.php
- Paid: https://www.axaio.com/doku.php/fr

---

A little tip on using any of these methods <sup><sub>(especially the script)</sub></sup> on mac: You can easily process files from completely different file paths by creating [`aliases`](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25250?locale=en_US) to the `.indd` files and putting those in the "input folder". That way you don't have to mess with the original file structure or like copy files over to the input folder every single time you make changes.

Comment: I've used Exportools Pro 4 since I got it for a few euros: http://exportoolspro.badiasoftware.com/ A little warning... While otherwise an amazing time saver... That specific app (v4), had an issue with its own preflight feature. Similar to indesign, it can tell you about possible issues, like low resolution image files in the document... except it failed to recognize effective ppi in pdf files.

Comment: The first link is dead, it seems like it has been moved to https://creativepro.com/files/kahrel/indesign/batch_convert.html.